# MKOverlayRenderer draw line using CGPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, mkoverlay

I'm trying to draw a line using `MKOverlayRenderer`. My overlay renderer's `drawMapRect` is roughly:

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, x, y) // x, y = starting point

let remainingPoints: [CGPoint] = ... // remaining points
CGPathAddLines(path, nil, remainingPoints, remainingPoints.count)

CGContextAddPath(context, path)

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)

CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

This however doesn't work, nothing appears. I also tried stroking with:

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, .Stroke)
```

I know my path is defined correctly because if I use `.FillStroke`, it fills the polygons.

Closing the path using `CGPathCloseSubpath(path)` doesn't help.

Comment: and when it does fill everything is in the location you expect it to be?

Comment: If I call `CGContextDrawPath(context, .FillStroke)` it fills the polygon, which is in the correct location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My line width (2.0) was too small the for the zoom level.

Comment: This saved me. Needed to push it to 400 to be seen, because i started on boundingRect MKMapRectWorld